# Fast way to acquire armor with item level higher than 615

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I hit level 100 yesterday and I wondered if any of you guys know a fast way to gear up for LFR once it's unlocked (people with ilvl < 615 can't queue up). The only way I get armor is doing instances, which takes incredibly long for a solo player like me (it takes up to one hour to find an instance group).

Comment: For anyone who queues as damage and isn't a strict solo player: tanks and healers drastically lower the queue time (down to a couple minutes usually). There's plenty of places outside of the dungeon finder to find others to queue with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have several legitimate options, some of which can be done in combination to speed things up:

1. Keep solo queuing dungeons.  The queue time might be long, but you're now [guaranteed an item off of the last boss](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/15355105387?page=127#2531).  That's a 615 piece on normal mode and 630 on heroic.
2. Buy PvP gear with Honor.  Honor vendor is in Stormshield (Alliance) or Warspear (Horde) next to Ashran.  Honor gear is 620 in PvE.  There is no longer a penalty for using PvP gear in PvE.
3. Crafting.  You can try crafting your own gear or buying it off the auction house.  If you don't have any crafting profession for your class, you can use your small garrison buildings to craft for you.  For example, the Level 3 Tailoring shop offers ilvl 640 epic gear.  The catch is it costs 100 cloth per piece, which can be time-consuming to farm via work orders.  I assume similar prices exist for the other professions.
4. Don't forget [Khadgar's legendary questline](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=35988).  The first part only requires normal Skyreach for an epic ilvl 640 ring and if you finish the first chapter the ring is upgraded to ilvl 680.
5. Rare level 100 and 100 (ilvl 615 requirement) follower missions can offer a token that generates a random ilvl 615 (and ilvl 630 for the latter) piece for one of your armor slots.  These missions aren't that common and are fairly long, but combined with the other options, can help boost you faster.
6. Various rare spawns around the world can drop ilvl 620 gear, but many of these have a long respawn timer.  Wowhead's guide to [gearing for heroic dungeons](http://www.wowhead.com/news=244538/guide-to-getting-the-ilvl-requirements-for-heroic-dungeons-610-and-molten-core-6) has a good list.
7. You can trade in thousands of Apexis shards for ilvl 630 gear at Stormshield/Warspear.
8. Highly overpriced Bind on Equip items at your local auction house, or if you're lucky your Level 3 Salvage Yard.  These are ilvl 621 for the rares and 665 for the epics.
9. Between [Nov 21st, 2014 and Jan 6, 2015](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/16889478/world-of-warcraft-10-year-anniversary-celebration-begins-tomorrow-11-20-2014), a special level 100 version of the 40-man Molten Core raid is available.  The final boss, Ragnaros, drops a guaranteed epic ilvl 640 hat.  The other nine bosses don't have any loot.  If you're a damage-dealer, be prepared to spend an hour in queue and around three hours to clear the instance, and make sure you bring a lot of patience.  You need ilvl 615 to enter, but it'll boost your ilvl for Blackrock Foundry, which is expected to have tougher requirements than Highmaul.

Comment: Guess that keeps me entertained until LFR gets activated, thanks!

Comment: Good detail, but a lot to digest. I would suggest picking up Khadgar's legendary questline for the ring and queuing specifically for Normal Skyreach to get it. Hopefully you got a few epic upgrades during questing, which will also bump you up some.  Other than that, run a few Normals until you're 610, then run a few Heroics to 615. A good tip to avoid the queue as DPS is to ask your group at the end of each dungeon if they'd like to immediately queue again as a group (many people don't know you can do this).  If the tank or healer is up for it, your times will be a lot less (if not instant).

Comment: Archaeology has a nice ilvl 620 one handed weapon, if you do the Arakkoa one : http://www.wowhead.com/item=117382

Comment: To shorten your queue times you could befriend a tank and queue together ;). I am mostly picking up 1 random DD from /1 because I am a nice guy.

Comment: queue times are awful, I am glad I have multiple accounts with a tank in one of it. Even healers don't have as fast of a queue as a tank does and I am on a highly populated realm.

Comment: Another useful thing to know is you can queue for multiple dungeons at the same time.  At least that way your wait times are concurrent not sequential.  The only gripe is you may not get a break for a while if you do this.   -- The queue for my tank pops almost instantly, so I never get to do this on that character.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Troyen, there's one more way (probably the fastest) to get a high ilvl fast:

Go to Ring of Trials (Nagrand), there's a vendor that sells "Warlords Tournament Season 1" PvP items (50 gold each piece, 750 gold for the whole set), all iLvl 660, you can't actually use them outside of war games, but it counts as your ilvl used to queue up, so you would be able to queue up all LFR raids.

To be honest I'm not a fan of doing it this way, because there will be a lot of iLvl 600 people getting into LFR having low DPS.

Comment: From which game is your avatar ?

Comment: Garrosh Hellscream from World of Warcraft

Comment: Using the Tournament Gear this way is unintended.  https://twitter.com/CM_Lore/status/534477126032846848

Comment: Never mentioned its intended for this, also said I'm not a fan doing it this way, but still, its the fastest working method.

Comment: lol this actually works, I used it to bypass iLvl requirement for heroic instances and I still deal highest DPS, I guess if only experienced players are going to make a use of this its not going to be too much of a problem

Comment: This method seems to be a bit wonky. I bought the items, and still couldn't get into a heroic (said I had 590/590). tried equipping them, same thing. Put them in my bank and started farming normals. Next day I log back in, and see that I'm suddenly queuing up for heroics (600/630) so it seemed to have worked.

Comment: Umm LFR/Flex is just Normal now.

Comment: Flex is normal, LFR still exists

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your dwarven bunker(lvl2) and salvage yard(lvl 2-3) and once you get 1 0r 2 followers to ilvl 640-645 you get highmaul missions which will reward you you great gear...easy and no q times!

Answer (score 0):

its not a lie but its not correct either the tournament gear is not sold at ring of trials, it is sold near highmaul in nagrand by an npc named Blarg. If you equip it your ilvl goes down because the gear scales. But if you just leave it in your bags and you can get a 660 ilvl

Comment: Well I never asked but for the Alliance the vendor is actually @ Ring of Tales, and LeagueOfWarcraft seems to be Alliance since he could buy it there. It does also not matter if you equip it or not (Although I would not suggest it, since it wont give you any stats), the iLvl that matters for queuing up will be raised to 660 anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Thats a lie. You cant get a whole set at Ring of Trials. You can get a weapon and that is it. and even though it says 660 ilvl it actually lowers your average. I got the axe and equipped it and my ilvl went down like 40 pts.

Comment: Not even going to argue about this...